# Eclipse disorders an XML file after pressing Ctrl + Shift + F

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, coding-style

Ctrl + Shift + F does a good job when putting java or layout files in order. But does it disorder things in a file which starts with `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` (as an example)?

**This is what I have.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><nine-patch android:src="@drawable/bg_list_row_pic" />
    </item>
    <item><nine-patch android:src="@drawable/bg_list_row_pic" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

**This would be much better.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/bg_list_row_pic" />
    </item>    
    <item>
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/bg_list_row_pic" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

I've skimmed over `Window - Preferences - XML` but haven't found anything to solve the matter.

**ADDITION.**

if I use `Format XML files using the standard Android XML...`, I have the following in a layout file, but a file containing a `<selector>` and `<item>`s looks properly (see "This would be much better" in this message).

**It doesn't suit me.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sixteenDp" android:paddingRight="@dimen/sixteenDp">

    <Button android:id="@+id/mainAct_btn_RunTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/sixteenDp" android:text="@string/run_test" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/mainAct_btn_ShowList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainAct_btn_RunTest" android:text="@string/show_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This layout file suits me.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sixteenDp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/sixteenDp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainAct_btn_RunTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/sixteenDp"
        android:text="@string/run_test" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainAct_btn_ShowList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainAct_btn_RunTest"
        android:text="@string/show_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Go to Windows->Preferences->Android->Editors and disable first line "Format XML files using the standard Android XML..."

Comment: thank you. It works in this particular case but if I use it for a layout file, the file will go into disorder

Comment: Are you sure? I purposely edited my layouts, when I pressed ctrl+shift+F they're all fine. What disorder did you observe, can you post it

Comment: Of course, the default xml formatter wouldn't rearrange the Androidy order of attributes. It will just format the right spacing and indentation.

Comment: > What disorder did you observe, can you post it
@Neoh, I posted

Comment: If I were you, I'll check the "Format XML files using the standard Android XML..." by default, and when it comes to xml that contains <selector.../> then uncheck it. It is a hassle of a few clicks, I know, but unil google fixes up this minor issue I think this is the best you can do.

Comment: yes I've already inclined to do it manually, too. Your last commentary is the answer to my question.